# How to post picture on facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, image

I'am trying to develop app which takes a picture and sends it to my facebook fan page. Tried lots of different ways to do that, but at best it shares only a message and if i try to post a picture, then it posts on my timeline but not my fan page. So the question would be:

- how to upload picture and message to facebook page (if it's possible)?

This is part of the code I'am using to post:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    WriteableBitmap LoadedPhoto = new WriteableBitmap(0,0);
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        LoadedPhoto.SetSource(fileStream);
                        LoadedPhoto.SaveJpeg(ms, LoadedPhoto.PixelWidth, LoadedPhoto.PixelHeight, 0, 95);
                        ms.Seek(0, 0);
                        byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length];
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(LoadedPhoto.PixelWidth);
                        ms.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        ms.Close();
                        var fbUpl = new Facebook.FacebookMediaObject
                        {
                            FileName = fileName,
                            ContentType = "image/jpg"
                        }.SetValue(data);
                        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        parameters["message"] = message;
                        parameters["file"] = fbUpl;

                        fb.PostAsync("{pageID}/photos", parameters, "post");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using the [Page Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens) when you're posting. That's the only way the API knows that you want to act as the Page and not the logged in user.

Comment: Thank you, but I have one more question. How I can let ordinary users post pictures on my fan page wall as well? Is it even possible to do that ?

Comment: Do a HTTP POST to `/<page_id>/feed' with a message param and the posting User's `access_token`. More details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)